# No network access from within Docker container on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I can't access internet from withing a docker container on CentOS 7.
I tried almost everything I can find online, even disabling firewalld does not do the trick.

I can ping from the host but not from inside the container.

```
ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=247 time=12.7 ms

docker run -it --rm alpine ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Here is the result from docker info.

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 27
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 27
 Images: 9
 Server Version: 19.03.6
 Storage Driver: devicemapper
  Pool Name: docker-253:0-135106576-pool
  Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
  Base Device Size: 10.74GB
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Udev Sync Supported: true
  Data file: /dev/loop0
  Metadata file: /dev/loop1
  Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
  Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
  Data Space Used: 1.371GB
  Data Space Total: 107.4GB
  Data Space Available: 37.14GB
  Metadata Space Used: 2.908MB
  Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
  Metadata Space Available: 2.145GB
  Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
  Deferred Removal Enabled: true
  Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
  Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
  Library Version: 1.02.158-RHEL7 (2019-05-13)
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 3.703GiB
 Name: aaa.bbb.fr
 ID: PFCS:N6PF:2M5Z:VFSI:IK66:RRYB:GP5U:UU5R:ICX2:YSHP:2ZMR:DULU
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: the devicemapper storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
```

And from uname -a.

```
Linux xxx.aaa-bbb.fr 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Server name has been "anonymized".

Comment: is your host a VM ? can you ping docker0 and host machine IP from within the container ?

Comment: Yes it is a VM. I'm not really good at networking, what do you mean by "can you ping docker0" ? If I understand well, I looked at my ifconfig and ping docker0 ip address (172.17.0.1) and I can't ping it from inside the container. Same for VM IP.

Comment: it could be a problem related to MTU size of your docker0 interface. What is the mtu size of this interface? can you also share your docker-compose file ?

Comment: MTU size is 1500 for docker0.

Comment: I don't use docker-compose in those tests. I just test pinging using alpine image ``docker run -it --rm alpine ping 1.1.1.1``

Comment: try this first create a n/w with mtu 1400, using command "docker network create --subnet=10.11.0.0/16 --opt com.docker.network.driver.mtu=1400  my-network"  and then  run container using this n/w "docker run --network my-network -it --rm alpine ping 1.1.1.1"  . Let me know if it works

Comment: I'm afraid it does not work either.
Could I give you any other information of importance?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you can try to get tcpdump on docker0 interface when you ping 172.17.0.1 from container

Comment: Ok so now that's a weird behaviour. I launch my ```docker run -it --rm alpine ping 1.1.1.1``` command. No ping go through. I execute ```tcpdump -n -i docker0``` on another shell. Now ping are working as expected. I stop tcpdump. Pings do not work anymore.

Comment: Here is the demonstration of what's going on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBMNawKsgjk

Comment: It seems that tcpdump set the interface to promiscuous mode and that's what make the networking working. If I run tcpdump with --no-promiscuous-mode, it does not work.

Comment: nice observation benjamin but it's weird behavior.

Comment: Ok we found the issue (at least part of it). It seems that SELinux policies are the problem. If we disable SELinux, everything is right. So our solution right now is to disable SELinux. Not ideal but well...

Answer (score 0):

You could try run the container in interactive mode:

```
docker run -it alpine /bin/sh
```

And use route command to check routing tables:

```
/ # route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

In my case, the "default" route uses the 172.17.0.1 gateway to connect the container to internet as the traceroute command shows:

```
/ # traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1)  0.016 ms  0.012 ms  0.011 ms
 2  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  0.821 ms  1.035 ms  0.909 ms
 3  192.168.15.1 (192.168.15.1)  5.828 ms  2.388 ms  1.385 ms
 4  *  *  *
 5  201-156-180-113.reservada.static.axtel.net (201.156.180.113)  4.354 ms  3.901 ms  3.768 ms
 6  189-211-110-77.static.axtel.net (189.211.110.77)  3.159 ms  3.586 ms  2.791 ms
 ...
 15  74.125.50.198 (74.125.50.198)  30.514 ms  209.85.172.106 (209.85.172.106)  32.289 ms  74.125.50.198 (74.125.50.198)  30.217 ms
16  108.170.240.129 (108.170.240.129)  31.972 ms  108.170.252.161 (108.170.252.161)  33.039 ms  31.773 ms
17  216.239.63.239 (216.239.63.239)  30.631 ms  209.85.243.255 (209.85.243.255)  31.615 ms  216.239.42.99 (216.239.42.99)  31.734 ms
18  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  31.240 ms  30.674 ms  30.885 ms
```